# How to use Porterduff.mode.overlay

Tags: android, image, porter-duff

How can I use the 'overlay' porterduff mode? What I want is something like the overlay mode in gimp. 'Overlay' is listed in the porterduff.mode 's documetnation [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html), but can't use it.

p.s. 
'Multiply' is not what I am looking for.

Comment: "But I can't use it." You need to be specific in *how* you are using it and *why* it "can't" be used like that. Show us what's working and what isn't. That said, I notice the `OVERLAY` mode has no calculation specified in the Javadoc. Odd.

Comment: When I type Mode.OVERLAY it is an error- "OVERLAY cannot be resolved or is not a field". Me too noticed that there is no calculation specified in the docs.

Comment: What I actually wanted was to convert a photo into a painting.I found a technique to do that - [link](http://www.tutorialkit.com/tutorials/Convert-image-to-painting-30972.html). But overlay filter is being used in it.